# plot the sorted weekdays/month on timeseries dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have an one year of traffic data stored in a data frame.

| study time | volume | month | hour | day | year | weekday | week_of_year | weekend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 25 | January | 0 | Tuesday | 2019 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:15 | 25 | January | 0 | Tuesday | 2019 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:30 | 21 | January | 0 | Tuesday | 2019 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:00 | 100 | January | 0 | Wednesday | 2019 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:15 | 2 | January | 0 | Wednesday | 2019 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-01-02 00:00:30 | 50 | January | 0 | Wednesday | 2019 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

I want to see the hourly, daily, weekly and monthly patterns on volume data. I did so using this script:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(16,10))
plt.axes(ax[0,0])

countData19_gdf.groupby(['hour','address']).mean().groupby(['hour'])['volume'].mean().plot(x='hour',y='volume')
plt.ylabel("Total averge counts of the stations")

plt.axes(ax[0,1])
countData19_gdf.groupby(['day','address']).mean().groupby(['day'])['volume'].mean().plot(x='day',y='volume')

plt.axes(ax[1,0])
countData19_gdf.groupby(['week_of_year','address']).mean().groupby(['week_of_year'])['volume'].mean().plot(x='week_of_year',y='volume', rot=90)
plt.ylabel("Total averge counts of the stations")

plt.axes(ax[1,1])
countData19_gdf.groupby(['month','address']).mean().groupby(['month'])['volume'].mean().plot(x='month',y='volume', rot=90)
plt.ylabel("Total averge counts of the stations")

ax[0,0].title.set_text('Hourly')
ax[0,1].title.set_text('Daily')
ax[1,0].title.set_text('Weekly')
ax[1,1].title.set_text('Monthly')

plt.savefig('temporal_global.png')
```

and the result looks like this, in which the weekdays is or months are not sorted.

[image]

Can you please help me with how I can sort them? I tried to sort days as integers but it does not work.

Comment: It would be helpful to have data as more than just an image.

Comment: I did try but it throws back an AttributeError
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_value'`

for example `months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
          "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
plt.axes(ax[1,1])
df1['month']= pd.Categorical(df1['month'], categories=months, ordered=True)
df1.sort_value(by="month")
df1.groupby(['month','address']).mean().groupby(['month'])['volume'].mean().plot(x='month',y='volume', rot=90)
plt.ylabel("Total averge counts of the stations")`

Comment: It's a method and it should be `sort_values` not `sort_value`

Comment: d'oh! thanks. I fixed it, it doesn't throw back an error anymore, the plot is empty though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The groupby method will automatically sort the index, however for string values, that means sorting alphabetically (and not by, for example, order of weekdays).

What you can do is use `reindex` method to have the index order how you would like it. For example:

```
countData19_gdf.groupby(['day','address']).mean().groupby(['day'])['volume'].mean().reindex(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']).plot(x='day',y='volume')
```

**Note:**

If value in index is not present in the list of values specified in `reindex` method, that row will not be included. Likewise, if there's a new value in that list, which is not present in the index, it will result in a `NaN` value assigned to that new index. So, if your `countData19_gdf` doesn't have `day` such as `Monday`, it will be present in the reindexed `df`, but the value will be set to `NaN`.

**Edit:**

Since you already have numerical values for weekday (you might want to get the same for months), to avoid specifying the new index by hand, you could get sorted string values via:

```
countData19_gdf.sort_values(by = 'weekday')['day'].unique()
```

**Quick example** (I changed around some 'day' values in the given data to display the issue):

```
df.groupby(['day','address']).mean().groupby(['day'])['volume'].mean().plot(x='day',y='volume')
```

Outputs:

[image]

```
df.groupby(['day','address']).mean().groupby(['day'])['volume'].mean().reindex(['Tuesday','Wednesday','Friday']).plot(x='day',y='volume')
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: If you trust panda’s locale setting `pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(1970, 1, 5), freq='d', periods=7).strftime('%A')` gets you the sorted list of days too. Similary with `(…, freq='m', periods=12).strftime('%B')` for months.

Comment: @Cimbali this is a great idea.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer and the examples. I did try it and it worked for the weekday but, for the month does not show any plot. `countData19_gdf.groupby(['month','address']).mean().groupby(['month'])['volume'].mean().reindex(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']).plot(x='month',y='volume')
`

Comment: @Raha1986 your month values in the DataFrame are full month names ('January', 'February', ...), but you reindex using shortened names ('Jan', 'Feb', ...). This is the thing I mentioned about new values resulting in `NaN` values. Since none of the shortened names are present in your DataFrame (specifically 'month' column), it only results in missing values.